# How do I display an array of Uint8 as an image on macOS using SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, core-graphics

I'm just starting to learn Xcode, SwiftUI, etc. by creating a learning app which is also useful. I am able to import data as [UInt16] and scale it to [UInt8] for display as a grayscale image.  I create a CGImage which is assigned to a state variable but I get this error:

> 2023-06-13 10:03:04.497662-0700 DisplayFM2Image[6160:76497] [default] CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0

I have a breakpoint just after the CGImage is created; when I inspect the image in a debug session the image is displayed! It appears that I'm doing something right, but the error appears when I 'continue' in debug.  I have not been able to figure out where  the error is generated but think it is in the display/view.  I keep the scaled [UInt8] and image metadata in an instance, theImage, of my class TheImage.

My suspicions are that the cgImage didn't retain the pointer to the image data (or some such) after the function "createCGImageFromUint8"returned or that the code in the GeometryReader is not correct.

The intent is to allow the user to pick a file containing the image data, display the data and let the user examine the unscaled data at the tool tip - and then repeat with another dataset.

(It's ironic that an earlier version of the app worked but I had not used best practices  - code in the ContentView that loaded and scaled the image might be called each time the ContentView updated. )

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics

// Calculates a Core Graphics image as ContentView's
// State variable "cgImage".
func createCGImageFromUint8( _ cgImage: inout CGImage?) {
    
    let width: Int = theImage.nCols
    let height: Int = theImage.nRows
    let numBytes = theImage.scaledArray.count
    let numComponents = numBytes / (height * width)
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let grayScaleData = CFDataCreate(nil, theImage.scaledArray, numBytes)
    let provider = CGDataProvider(data: grayScaleData!)!
    
    cgImage = CGImage(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bitsPerPixel: 8 * numComponents,
        bytesPerRow: width * numComponents,
        space: colorspace,
        //bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0),
        bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue),
        provider: provider,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true,
        intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!
    
    // break point
     print("Return from createCGImageFromUint8")
    // Looking at cgImage in debug at this breakpoint
    // displays the image!
}
```

This is the start of my ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics

var theImage = TheImage() // Image vars, file

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var haveNewImage: Bool = false
    @State private var cgImage: CGImage? = nil
        
    // @State var imageDataView: (any View)? // what's this?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading ) {
            
            FilePickerView(cgImage: $cgImage)
                .padding()  // at upper left corner WORKS
            
            // If a new file was picked: process and display it.
            if theImage.isNew { // displays image etc. GOAT
                Text("DEBUG New Image")
                CGImageView(cgImage: $cgImage)
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Image not yet selected.")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

This is my CGImageView.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics
import AppKit

struct CGImageView: View {
    @Binding var cgImage: CGImage?

    @State private var opacity = 0.0
    @State private var minMax = theImage.minMax
    @State private var dnData: [UInt16] = theImage.backingArray
    
    var body: some View {
        var dnText = "" // to display tooltip
        Text(theImage.displayName)
            .padding(10)
        
        HStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
            //    Image(decorative: $cgImage as! CGImage , scale: 1.0)
                  Image(decorative: self.cgImage! , scale: 1.0)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .border(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(width: CGFloat(theImage.nCols), height: CGFloat(theImage.nRows))
            .opacity(opacity)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5), value: opacity)
            
            .onAppear {
                opacity = 1.0
            }
            
            .onDisappear {
                opacity = 0.0
            }
            
            .onTapGesture {
                print("TAPPED!") // do something
            }
            .onHover { (hover: Bool) in
                if hover {
                    //   let mouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation
                    //   print("Mouse location: \(mouseLocation)")
                    NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                } else {
                    NSCursor.pop()
                }
            }
            
            .onContinuousHover { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .active(let location):  // col, row
                    let dn = theImage.getToolTipValue(mouse: location)
                    dnText = "raw DN \(dn)"
                    print("---> location x: \(location.x)")
                case .ended:
                    break
                }
            }
            .padding(10)

            Text("Mimimum \(minMax[0])\nMaximum \(minMax[1])\n\(dnText)")
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call `createCGImageFromUint8` in your code. Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx I've added the view that makes the createCGImageFromUint8 call.  I've not been able to make a minimal reproducible example for this.

Comment: @jnpdx I was able to create a minimal example and received an error message that led me to a solution. The CGImage is immutable and my use effectivly tried to change it.

Comment: @jnpdx I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

In creating a working minimal example I found that a CGImage is immutable and I was effectivly mutating it.  I fixed the problem by storing the CGImage in my TheImage class along with the code that generates the CGImage.

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

var theImage = TheImage()

struct ContentView: View {
    
    //@State var cgImage: CGImage? = nil
    @State var haveImage: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                theImage.makeScaledArray()
                theImage.createCGImageFromUint8()
                haveImage = true
            }) {
                Text("Click here!")
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            
            if(haveImage) {
                CGImageView()
            } else {
                Text("Image will display here.")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This class holds the scaled array (and will hold the original data) and functions that operate on the data.

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

class TheImage {
    
    init() {
    }
    
    var nCols: Int = 320
    var nRows: Int = 240
    var scaledArray: [UInt8]?
    var cgImage: CGImage?
    
    func makeScaledArray() {
        let size: Int = self.nCols * self.nRows
        var array: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: size)
        for i in 0..<size {
            array[i] = UInt8(i % 256)
        }
        self.scaledArray = array
    }
    
    func createCGImageFromUint8() {
        
        let width = self.nCols
        let height = self.nRows
        let numBytes = self.scaledArray!.count
        let numComponents = numBytes / (height * width)
        let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let grayScaleData = CFDataCreate(nil, self.scaledArray, numBytes)
        let provider = CGDataProvider(data: grayScaleData!)!
        
        self.cgImage = CGImage(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bitsPerPixel: 8 * numComponents,
            bytesPerRow: width * numComponents,
            space: colorspace,
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue),
            provider: provider,
            decode: nil,
            shouldInterpolate: true,
            intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
        
        print("DEBUG cgImage created.")
    }


}
```

Lastly the ImageView including a bit of display sugar.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics
import AppKit

struct CGImageView: View {
    @State private var opacity = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                //    Image(decorative: $cgImage as! CGImage , scale: 1.0)
                Image(decorative: theImage.cgImage! , scale: 1.0)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .border(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(width: CGFloat(theImage.nCols), height: CGFloat(theImage.nRows))
            .opacity(opacity)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5), value: opacity)
            
            .onAppear {
                opacity = 1.0
            }
            
            .onDisappear {
                opacity = 0.0
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding(10)
        
        }
    
}
```